# file-write output without quotation marks

Tags: netlogo

I want to write an output file with some information in Netlogo. It works fine so far but i wonder if i can write strings without quotation marks. It would help me alot in analysing my data. I could use another programm to delete the quotation marks but i would like to generate the file without them if its possible.

For example: i want to generate the output:

2_100_1 / 0.05081157374735357

3_100_1 / 0.09989594172736732

but i get the output

"2_100_1 / 0.05081157374735357"

"3_100_1 / 0.09989594172736732"

The problem seems to be that i use word, but i have no idea how i can fix this.

Any help is appreciated

```
file-write (word frequenz "_" transferrate "_" dangerradius " / " (overall-wait / ticks))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `file-print` instead.

From the Netlogo Dictionary:

file-write outputs quotes around strings.

> file-write value This command will output value, which can be a number,
>   string, list, boolean, or nobody to an opened file, not followed by a
>   carriage return (unlike file-print and file-show).
>
> This agent is not printed before the value, unlike file-show. Its
>   output also includes quotes around strings and is prepended with a
>   space. It will output the value in such a manner that file-read will
>   be able to interpret it.
>
> Note that this command is the file i/o equivalent of write, and
>   file-open needs to be called before this command can be used.

file-print:

> file-print value Prints value to an opened file, followed by a
>   carriage return.
>
> This agent is not printed before the value, unlike file-show.
>
> Note that this command is the file i/o equivalent of print, and
>   file-open needs to be called before this command can be used.
>
> See also file-show, file-type, file-write, and Output (programming
>   guide).